# Javascript ignore function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I am working on a site at work. It is a business application running on Spring MVC tiles with a Tomcat server. The real question is this. There is a function that is passed into each tile that ignores the enter key on the forms. Is there a short javascript function to ignore a javascript function(as fun as that sounds)? For exanmple, there is a create form where you should not be able to press enter but above the form is a search box where you should be able to press enter. One is navbar.jsp and other is create***********.jsp. I have spent a couple of hours doing research on here and doing the tried and true method of just trying anything but could not figure it out. It would be really great if I could override that function in the navbar.jsp for example and still run the function in the create form. Here is the StopRKey function:

```js
function stopRKey(evt) {
//  var evt  = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
    var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
//  if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text")) { return false; }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13 && node.type=="text") {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The first 3 lines are the old code. We recycled one of the lines into our new snippet

Comment: Could you use a global toggle variable to decide to whether do something or nothing in the function? Or you could use jQuerys [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function on the event handler.

Comment: Just change the selector from window to your create form.  For instance $('#createForm').keydown(....

Comment: check the event target to see if it's the one you want?

Comment: wwwmarty the only problem with that is there are many pages in this project and this is in the layout. All the pages have different form names to work with that page's controller and other javascript functions. I see what you are saying though. Someone else suggested I create a flag on the tiles I do not want it to load on and then just check for that flag when the js on the layout loads.